# Add no-index to multiple categories and the products in them - Rankmath Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have categories with products in them on my WordPress site that I would like to "hide" from search engines by adding no-index. I could hide them manually with Rankmath (But this would take forever...)

So what I'm looking for is something like:

If -> category = t-shirt (Add no-index)
If -> category = Pants (Add no-index)

And so on.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### You're looking for `is_product_category()`

> Returns true when viewing a product category archive.

- Source @ https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5

---

Setting up a `<meta name="robots">` tag to either `content="all"` or `content="none"` will askg robots to index or ignore.

On a product category page:

```
<?php if ( is_product_category( array( 'shirts', 'games', ) ) ) : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="none">
<?php else : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
<?php endif; ?>
```

On a single product page:

```
<?php if ( is_product() && has_term( array( 'shirts', 'games', ), 'product_cat', wc_get_product()->get_id() ) ) : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="none">
<?php else : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help!